# Anyway to replace IntelliJ with vim/emacs + commandline?

Tags: java, vim, maven, intellij-idea, jetty

I was looking to replace some of the most frequently used settings I have for IntelliJ with vim (or emacs, if needed) & command line tools.

I use

- Auto-import of libraries
- Deployment of various services in Jetty with debugging (I use breakpoints a lot)
- Go to declaration, implementation, and tests.
- JavaLint (?) basically something like PyFlakes for Java which shows warnings, errors in-line

I like IntelliJ but have been having a ton of problems with it lately and I miss not being able to use VIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://eclim.org promises to let you use Eclipse as a headless backend for vim.  So you could work entirely in vim, but have all the Java features of Eclipse (which are probably similar enough to IntelliJ Idea to meet your needs).

(That said, I've never gotten it to work, but it sounds good every time I hear about it.)

Comment: I got it to work and it's pretty cool but it's way slower than IntelliJ. I'm going to have to look at this further and figure out if there's ways to speed it up. It has all the features I use regularly except I still have to figure out how to setup breakpoints and deploy as easily as IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

I use JDEE with emacs + maven for builds (i use [pom-parser.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JdeeAndMaven2Pom) to better integrate maven with emacs).  To your points:

- Auto-import of libraries

  - built into JDEE
- Deployment of various services in Jetty with debugging (I use breakpoints a lot)

  - pretty sure you can deploy with maven + [jdibug](http://code.google.com/p/jdibug/) is a pretty decent emacs java debugger
- Go to declaration, implementation, and tests.

  - TAGS is built into emacs, and [GTAGS](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc.html) (aka global) is even better
- JavaLint (?) basically something like PyFlakes for Java which shows warnings, errors in-line

  - you can use the eclipse batch compiler with flymake for on-the-fly compilation errors/warnings

Comment: I'll have to take a look at this further, but I have very little experience with Emacs so I try to resist using it but there's just way too many good plugins that it has to ignore forever.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this [IdeaVim](http://ideavim.sourceforge.net/). It's a Vim emulation plug-in for IDEs based on the IntelliJ platform.

Comment: Haven't found a better combination so far. :(